# Impediment of new questions

Tags: discussion

After I asked my first question, it was put [on hold], this is ok, but when I was trying to ask another one, the "Post Your Question" button did not work, nothing happened.

Is it normal to be unable to ask a second question soon after the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - if your posts are poorly received, or if you are a new user, there is an element of rate limiting. This is to ensure people who don't yet know how the site works, and the scope of the site, don't post a number of bad questions.

It also helps with spam prevention.

Comment: thanks you for ter answer.